# Java - Logback to display testcase name

Tags: java, selenium, logback, slf4j

I am using Logback in my Selenium Webdriver project and I've reached a bit of a roadblock. I've search online but not been able to find the answer.

I am trying to find a way which allows me to get the testcase name (testGoogleWebsite) once inside the `setup()` method. So instead of just printing **"Starting test"** it prints out **"Starting test - testGoogleWebsite"**

I know I can do `LOG.debug("testGoogleWebsite");` on the first line of each test, but wanted to know if there's a better way.

My Test:

```
@Test
 public void testGoogleWebsite() {
    openGoogleWebsite();
    searchForStackOverflow();
    clickOnStackOverflowLink();
}


@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws FileNotFoundException {
    LOG.debug("Starting test - ");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown(){
    LOG.debug("End of test");
}
```

My logback file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="target/Logs" />

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about logging your testacse name (as testGoogleWebsite is a testcase name I see). To do this you can put your  `LOG.debug("Starting test - ");` in beforeMethod.

**Code snippet**

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(Method method) {
  LOG.debug("Starting test - " + method.getName(););
}
```

This will log your each and every testcase name as you wanted.